# Why does this .net regex not work?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, frameworks, expression

```
@"\[ [~\w]+ \]"
```

Why does this regular expression not work to find [~dp0] in the string "blah blah dummy text [~dp0]"

Comment: Because there are no spaces in `[~dp0]`. Anything else?

Comment: Are there so many down votes because you suspect this is a homework question or what?

Comment: should it matter if it's homework? it's a valid question. probably doesn't deserve any upvotes but 4 down votes?? come on...

Comment: @FishBasketGordo: Maybe because at the beginning the title was *Very Quick, why does this .net regex not work?*. And some problems can be solved by playing around a bit. There is no indication of the OP trying to  solve the problem by himself.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the spaces. It should be `\[[~\w]+\]` or use the option `IgnorePatternWhiteSpace`.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah... It's the spaces.

```
@"\[[~\w]+\]"
```

If you want to ignore the spaces in the pattern, you can use RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace:

```
Regex.Match ("blah blah dummy text[~p0]". @"\[ [~\w]+ \]", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```